# Styling dropdown using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the dropdown similar to the image [image: here]. I am close but there are few things which I am unable to figure out. 
- How can I add the lines between each item in the list
- How can I make the list start from under the "SELECT".

[image: This] is what I have so far.

Is there a better way to do this without using CSS? I am fairly new to CSS.

I am not sure how my question is similar. If someone can explain. The post does not have similarity to what I am trying to achieve.

```css
.dropbtn {
    color: white;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 900;
    background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.sphere {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    /* position: relative; */
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -55px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    table-layout: fixed;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding: 12px 16px 13px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a {
 background:url('sidearrow.png') no-repeat left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background:url('sidewhite.png') no-repeat left;
 background-color: rgb(255,131,0);
 color:white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

div#arrow {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdown.css">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">SELECT</button>
  <div class="sphere">
   <div id="arrow">
    <img src="arrow.png" width="29" height="27" alt=""/>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SebastianBrosch can you explain how is it similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to adjust some sizes, but it works:

```css
.dropbtn {
    color: white;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 900;
    background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
  z-index:1;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  right: 5px;
  top:-20px;
}
.sphere {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    /* position: relative; */
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -55px;
  z-index:2;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    table-layout: fixed;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding: 12px 16px 13px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: none;
}
.dropdown-content a:first-child {
  padding-top:22px;
}
.dropdown a {
  
 background:url('sidearrow.png') no-repeat left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background:url('sidewhite.png') no-repeat left;
 background-color: rgb(255,131,0);
 color:white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

div#arrow {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdown.css">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">SELECT</button>
  <div class="sphere">
   <div id="arrow">
    <img src="arrow.png" width="29" height="27" alt=""/>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.dropbtn {
    color: white;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 900;
    background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.sphere {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    /* position: relative; */
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -55px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    table-layout: fixed;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 6px;
    padding: 12px 16px 13px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a {
 background:url('sidearrow.png') no-repeat left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background:url('sidewhite.png') no-repeat left;
 background-color: rgb(255,131,0);
 color:white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

div#arrow {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdown.css">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">SELECT</button>
  <div class="sphere">
   <div id="arrow">
    <img src="arrow.png" width="29" height="27" alt=""/>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a><hr/>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a><hr/>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a><hr/>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mani -Please add <hr/> between the select options.
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a><hr/>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a><hr/>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a><hr/>
  </div>

Comment: Thank you for the input but how can I make this start from under the select just like the image, Also if you could explain why the hover (orange) does not cover the entire select item area

Comment: .dropdown-content { min-width:180px;}

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a `border-bottom: 1px solid black` and you're done.

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmumvm6v/)

```css
.dropbtn {
  color: white;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 900;
  background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
  border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.sphere {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* position: relative; */
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: -55px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  table-layout: fixed;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 12px 16px 13px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.dropdown a {
  background: url('sidearrow.png') no-repeat left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background: url('sidewhite.png') no-repeat left;
  background-color: rgb(255, 131, 0);
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

div#arrow {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">SELECT</button>
  <div class="sphere">
    <div id="arrow">
      <img src="arrow.png" width="29" height="27" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the input. How can I make the element list start just the way in the picture. My select item lists starts from a side where as I want it to be under.

Comment: @mani you're welcome. what do you mean? you mean it should start right below the select?

Answer (score 1):

Check this provide below jsfiddle, make changes in your `.dropdown-content` i.e. add `left` and `margin` values and set it's `z-index` value to `-1`, now to add border, you can make use of border-bottom in `.dropdown-content a`.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tg997fg3/3/)

```
.dropdown-content{
    left:8px;
    margin-top:-5px;
    z-index:-1;
    ..........
    ..........
    ..........
}

.dropdown-content a {
 border-bottom:1px solid #111;
    ..........
    ..........
    ..........
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.dropbtn {
    color: white;
    width: 180px;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 900;
    background: rgba(0, 173, 239, 1);
    border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
     z-index:2;
 position:relative;

}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 177px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   margin-top:-20px;
    left:2px;
    z-index:0;
}
.sphere {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    /* position: relative; */
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -55px;
}
.dropdown-content a:first-child{
  padding-top: 30px;
 }
.dropdown-content a {
    table-layout: fixed;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px 13px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
 .dropdown-content a{
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:0;
 }
 .dropdown-content a:last-child{
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  }
.dropdown a {
 background:url('sidearrow.png') no-repeat left;
 }

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background:url('sidewhite.png') no-repeat left;
 background-color: rgb(255,131,0);
 color:white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

div#arrow {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdown.css">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">SELECT</button>
  <div class="sphere">
   <div id="arrow">
    <img src="arrow.png" width="29" height="27" alt=""/>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```